# display a toast from BatteryService.java

Tags: android

I am working on my own android build for my own device, not using some commercial cell phone. 
This means that I control the platform/android build. i.e. I am not working on app on top of android, I am working inside of android itself.

I am trying to display a toast (or notify the user any other way) of the reason why shutdownIfOverTemp() is shutting down (e.g. diplay a toast "battery is overheating, shutting down"). The reason for this is the battery I am running has additional shutdown conditions and I want the user to know which one is in play (without having to look at some logs)

while Google called the file AndroidService.java, it is not service in that it doesn't extend Service, it extends Binder (full source here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/server/BatteryService.java/)

I don't know how to get a context to pass to Toast:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Battery overheating!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

does NOT work, I get an undefined symbol on getApplicationContext():

```
target Java: services (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/services_intermediates/classes)
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java:244: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getApplicationContext()
location: class com.android.server.BatteryService
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Battery overheating!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

adding this doesn't help either:

```
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
```

Comment: there is a context param `public BatteryService(Context context, LightsService lights)` use the context to dispaly toast.  `mContext = context;` use `mContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class extends binder

```
class BatteryService extends Binder {
```

but the method BatteryService is called with a context as one of its arguments already:

```
public  BatteryService(Context context, LightsService lights) {
    mContext = context;
```

so use mContest when calling toast instead of getApplicationContest

Give that a try and report back.

Comment: Thanks. Raghunandan answered before you did (in the comments) and you both have the same answer, and it allowed me to fix my problem. I want to mark this as resolved/answered and I guess you get the credit since you have an answer instead of juxt a comment. Sorry Raghunandan and thanks for the help.